# Batch scripting - echo device vendor and model with formatted output?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm trying to get my batch file to output the Vendor name and model of my Laptop, but I can't seem to get it formatted. Can someone help me to find a solution?

EDIT: Thank you for the answers, all of them work as I need it!

This is what I've got:

```
@echo off
set /a cnt=0
echo|set/p "=Vendor: "
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('wmic csproduct get vendor') do (echo|set/p "=%%i")
set /a cnt=0
echo:
echo|set/p "=Name: "
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%j in ('wmic csproduct get name') do (echo|set/p "=%%j ")
echo:
pause
```

Output:

```
Vendor: Vendor  HP
Name: Name                         HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM 35W
```

My desired Output would be this:

```
Vendor: HP
Name: HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM 35W
```

Comment: That's due to the formatting of wmic. You can try something like this: `for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3* delims=," %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe csproduct get vendor^,name /format:csv') do set "name=%%g" & set "vendor=%%h"` and then you can do `echo Vendor %vendor%` then `echo Name: %name%` to display the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest a slightly different version?

```
@echo off
echo|set/p "=Vendor: "
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic csproduct get vendor /value') do (echo|set/p "=%%i")
echo:
echo|set/p "=Name: "
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic csproduct get name /value') do echo|set /p "=%%i"
echo:
pause
```

`/value` avoids the spaces for formatting as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip the first line of each output.

try this:

```
@echo off
set /a cnt=0
echo|set/p "=Vendor: "
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%i in ('wmic csproduct get vendor') do (echo|set/p "=%%i")
set /a cnt=0
echo:
echo|set/p "=Name: "
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%j in ('wmic csproduct get name') do (echo|set/p "=%%j ")
echo:
pause
```

Comment: Keeps some trailing spaces after the value (not visible with this output, but might lead to problems in other cases).  (change `echo:` to `echo::` in both yours and mine to see the difference.

Comment: The @Stephan answer looks great!

Answer (score 0):

Using the same, *(now deprecated)*, `WMIC` utility, this is how I'd get that specific output, *without the need to define variables*:

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bash
(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %G In ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CSProduct Get Name,Vendor /Value 2>NUL"') Do @If Not "%~H" == "" For /F "Tokens=*" %I In ("%G: %~H") Do @Echo %I) | %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /R
```

And in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bash
@(For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('
 "%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe CSProduct Get Name,Vendor /Value 2>NUL"'
 ) Do @If Not "%%~H" == "" For /F "Tokens=*" %%I In ("%%G: %%~H") Do @Echo %%I
) | %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /R
```

Comment: This one works as well as the others, thank you!